# Chars-Counter Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for a solution:

Input is a string like `s = "Hello World!"`
The function should return a dictionary like:
`{'e': 1, 'H': 1, 'r': 1, 'o': 2, 'd': 1, ' ': 1, 'l': 3, 'W': 1}`

i just got an inefficient solution with `get`:

```
def char_count_dict(count_string):
     letter_dict = {}
     for letter in count_string:
         letter_dict[letter] = letter_dict.get(letter, 0)+1
     return letter_dict
```

Comment: You don't seem to ignore punctuation signs at any point?

Comment: Why do you thing your implmentation is _inefficient_? You'll obviously get an answers with `.setdefault`, `defaultdict` and `collections.Counter` but effectively they all do same thing as your `.get` under the hood.

Comment: So maybe add some logic to check the dtype of the indivudual characters, and then build a Counter

Comment: "inefficient solution".the time complexity is O(n).I think it is good.

Comment: It should contain the str.count-function and a dictionary comprehension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use high-performance container datatypes like `collections.Counter`
https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

```
from collections import Counter

def char_count_dict(count_string):
    return dict(Counter(count_string))
```

Comment: It should contain the str.count-function and a dictionary comprehension.